# Group by in Sequelize when using a function

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to group by the values returned by a function, as such:

```
    let noticesOpened = NoticeOpened.aggregate(
        "id",
        "COUNT", {
            plain: false,
            where: noticeWhere,
            group: [sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "day", sequelize.col("created_at"))],
            order: [
                ["created_at", "ASC"]
            ],
        });
    return noticesOpened;
```

When I try this query I get:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: column "notice_opened_tbl.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is there a way to do an ascending order on the returned grouped value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order by the result of the function from the group clause, e.g. something like:

```js
    let noticesOpened = NoticeOpened.aggregate(
        "id",
        "COUNT", {
            plain: false,
            where: noticeWhere,
            group: [sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "day", sequelize.col("created_at"))],
            order: [
                [sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "day", sequelize.col("created_at")), "ASC"]
            ],
        });
    return noticesOpened;
```

I think to remember you can use sequelize aliases to make this easier but don't have the syntax to hand.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me

Comment: Awesome! Have a great day!